# HDD Datastore goes offline when VM Starts

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a VMWare ESXI 6.7 host that has 2 VM's on it (pfSense and FreePBX).

When I start the pfSense machine I get a lot of errors about iSCSI and the data storage within VMware goes offline. The box has 1 HDD connected via SATA to the  MB (Avoton Board). When this happens I cannot browse the datastore.

The only way I can recover is to reboot the server. Everything was fine last week but I am having issues now.

Could it be a fault disk, bad drivers etc?

Answer (score 2):

It can be both related to ESXi and Hard Disk health state. ESXi always records SMART of the disk, so check out the ESXi logs and submit a support request to VMware support